# ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename

Tags: angular, ubuntu-14.04, shared-directory

I have just started working with angular2.
Ubuntu 14.04 VMplayer
Shared Folder **devcode**

I am running ubuntu on VM windows host, used shared folders on Linux to get windows hosted folder and files into Linux development environment.When I try to do npm install for dependencies
Hit **npm install** in terminal

```
54094 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/mnt/hgfs/devcode/angularApp/node_modules/.dashdash.DELETE/node_modules/assert-plus' -> '/mnt/hgfs/devcode/angularApp/node_modules/dashdash/node_modules/assert-plus'
54095 verbose cwd /mnt/hgfs/devcode/angularApp
54096 error Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
54097 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
54098 error node v7.6.0
54099 error npm  v4.1.2
54100 error path /mnt/hgfs/devcode/angularApp/node_modules/.dashdash.DELETE/node_modules/assert-plus
54101 error code ENOENT
54102 error errno -2
54103 error syscall rename
```

After `dir and ls`
[image]

Comment: do `dir` or `ls`

Answer (score 4):

This looks like [npm issue #17444](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444) (which is probably several different issues, actually). The things you should try to resolve it are:

1. Remove your `package-lock.json` and let npm recreate it with (usually slightly updated) versions of packages. This is what worked for me recently. If you're not committing your `package-lock.json` you should be doing so, but why is a matter for another question.
2. Ensure that you've exited any programs such as Visual Studio Code or other things that might be holding locks on the files. This is not likely to be much of a problem on Linux (or anything with POSIX filesystem semantics), but definitely can be a problem on Windows.
3. Ensure that you're using a local filesystem and not a network filesystem of some sort (that, again, may not have POSIX semantics).

Comment: What worked for me was manually adding it to package.json, and then deleting package-lock + node_modules, and reinstalling

Comment: Remember to exit Visual Studio, I was stuck on this